# column's type changed when concatenating scraped dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having some troubles and I couldn't find any answers on the internet (which is very rare !!)

I'm doing some webscraping (meterological data) on a daily granularity by city.
When I scrape for 1-day, the 'city' column is considered string, but when i scrape on more than 1-day like 2-days, the 'city' column is not a string anymore and the same code that used to work when 1-day scrape doesnt work anymore on a 2-days scrape.

Here's my code for **scraping**

```
url_template = 'https://www.wetterkontor.de/de/wetter/deutschland/extremwerte.asp?id={}'
def get_weather(date):
  url = url_template.format(date)
  html_doc = requests.get(url).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
  table = soup.find('table', id="extremwerte")

  rows = []
  for row in table.find_all('tr'):
      rows.append([val.text for val in row.find_all('td')])

  headers= [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
  df = pd.DataFrame(rows[2:], columns=headers)
  df['date']=date
  return df

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
for d in pd.date_range(start='20170101', end='20170101'):
df2=pd.concat([df2,get_weather(d.strftime('%Y%m%d'))])
```

When I only scrape for 20170101 like above, this below line of code works :

```
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
  if isinstance(df2['Wetterstation\xa0'][i],str) is True:
      df2.at[i,'Wetterstation\xa0']=df2['Wetterstation\xa0'][i].replace('/','-')
```

But when I change the end date to 20170202 for exemple, the code won't work and give me this error message :
**AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'**

Please can you explain me what has changed ? Why the type of columns changes when I scrape more than one day ?

Thank you in advance for your time !

Comment: FYI pandas can directly read HTML containing tables into a list of dataframes with `pd.read_html(url)`. Not sure what the underlying problem is, but this may help.

Comment: Thank you @BallpointBen, when I use `pd.read_html(url)` I loose the comma for the decimal values so a value that is for exemple = '5,7' will be scrapped as ='57'. Do you know how to avoid this problem :) ?

Comment: @BallpointBen I managed to do it thanks to this `pd.read_html(url, decimal=',', thousands='.')` Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to specify correct parser, in this case `lxml` (standard `html.parser` produces incorrect results).

Running this code for end date `20170202`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_template = 'https://www.wetterkontor.de/de/wetter/deutschland/extremwerte.asp?id={}'
def get_weather(date):
    url = url_template.format(date)
    html_doc = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')   # <--- specify `lxml` parser
    table = soup.find('table', id="extremwerte")

    rows = []
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        rows.append([val.text for val in row.find_all('td')])

    headers= [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows[2:], columns=headers)
    df['date']=date
    return df

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
for d in pd.date_range(start='20170101', end='20170202'):
    df2=pd.concat([df2,get_weather(d.strftime('%Y%m%d'))])
print(df2)
```

Produces:

```
                               Wetterstation  MinimumTemp.[°C] MaximumTemp.[°C] Minimum 5 cmüber dem Erd-boden (Nacht) Schnee-höhe[cm] StärksteWindböe[Bft] Nieder-schlag[l/m2] Sonnen-scheindauer[h]      date
0                                      Aachen             -5,1              1,9                                   -6,9               0                  644                 1,9                   5,3  20170101
1                         Ahaus (Münsterland)             -1,2              0,7                                     -1               0                  429                 3,9                     0  20170101
2           Albstadt (Schwäbische Alb, 759 m)             -9,9              4,2                                  -10,8                                                        0                   7,1  20170101
3      Aldersbach (Lkr. Passau, Niederbayern)             -8,3             -1,7                                   -7,8                                                        0                   4,9  20170101
4                              Alfeld (Leine)             -4,1              1,6                                   -4,4               0                  322                 1,6                   1,5  20170101
..                                        ...              ...              ...                                    ...             ...                  ...                 ...                   ...       ...
965                               Zernien (N)                                                                                                                                 0                        20170202
966                               Zielitz (N)                                                                                                                                 0                        20170202
967  Zinnwald-Georgenfeld (Erzgebirge, 877 m)             -7,4              0,2                                   -0,2              55                  540                 0,5                     0  20170202
968                                 Zugspitze             -7,3             -5,3                                                    235                12123                   0                   5,8  20170202
969         Zwiesel (Bayerischer Wald, 612 m)             -4,4              9,3                                   -0,3              44                  213                 0,1                   2,4  20170202

[27841 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej, unfortunately I still have the same problem. For exemple, this line of code below will work when only one day is scrapped, but not when two days are scrapped.
    `df2['Wetterstation\xa0'].split(' (')[0]` 
This will now give me this error : **'Series' object has no attribute 'split'**